# ThreeNodes.js / NodeJS / CoffeeScript - Error During Build to Static JS

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, webgl

I ran server.js with node and everything worked perfectly. It's when I try to run the build script to create a compiled static version. I should also mention that it does output most of the files, but then throws an error mid-way.

**I ran:**

```
node server.js build
```

It seemed to work fine until it got to "Starting to Optimize the javascripts..."

**Error Output:**

```
/root/threenodes/ThreeNodes.js/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:14153
                throw new Error(errorMsg);
                      ^
Error: TypeError: Object function () {
            //A version of a require function that passes a moduleName
            //value for items that may need to
            //look up paths relative to the moduleName
            var args = aps.call(arguments, 0), lastArg;
            if (enableBuildCallback &&
                    isFunction((lastArg = args[args.length - 1]))) {
                lastArg.__requireJsBuild = true;
            }
            args.push(relMap);
            return func.apply(null, args);
        } has no method 'nameToUrl'
In module tree:
    threenodes/App
      order

    at Object.load (eval at <anonymous> (/root/threenodes/ThreeNodes.js/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:13687:38))
```

Comment: Ref to ThreeNodes.js Build Example:
https://github.com/idflood/ThreeNodes.js#build--deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just committed a fix to threenodes.js which should resolve your issue. It was caused by the fact that requirejs has been updated and the !order plugin is now deprecated. So the fix was simply to define a more precise version of requirejs in package.json.

https://github.com/idflood/ThreeNodes.js/commit/440757aa579ae3d35354e960a2bd5745bdee6847

To fix it:

- git pull origin master
- npm install -d
- node server.js build

As a side note, the dev branch use the new version of requirejs. It's still not merged on master because I've started to work on "node grouping" but it is not finished yet. Apart from this all other functionality should work the same way as on the master branch. So if you plan to develop something on top of threenodes I would recommend to use the dev branch ; ]

Comment: I tip my hat to you sir, it did work. Also, very nice tool you've created. This node approach reminds me a bit of Apple Shake. Any influence?

Comment: I think I might have tried shake once, but overall I always liked the node approach. Some time ago I used the maya nodes on a daily basis and tried once vvvv on windows. I immediately was impressed by it and wanted the same on osx... So this project is really experimental, and at the start it was mainly to see if something like that is possible in the browser.